# How to get all table cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to get all of cells in UITableView, I have tried [self.tableView visibleCells] but it just return the visible cells. Because I have a switch on my table cells, I want to loop all of cells to check if it is on or off.This is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *settings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *cells = [self.tableView visibleCells];
NSMutableArray * saveCodes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(FilterTableCell *cusCell in cells){
    if(cusCell.typeSwitch.isOn == TRUE){
        [saveCodes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:cusCell.locationTypeID]];
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: what do you need it for? Cells should be reusable so I'm not sure whether can you achieve what you planned anyway. Can't you base on the model which you are using for filling cells with data?

Comment: I think you need a separate array data source to identify which row has the on/off switch rather than associate that value with a particular cell. Your cell or cell class should be used for presentation not storing data (MVC pattern) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using a UITableView, it reuses your cells to optimize your memory. It loads the number of cells which can be drawn on your screen, and use them again when you are scrolling.  That's why you can only get the visible cells, and not all of them.

If you want to know which cells are on/off, you have to keep another array and use it to check your cell's state.

Moreover, your cells shouldn't have its own states, it should be known only by your controller if you are using the MVC pattern. You can use for example, an action, a block, or a delegate. Objective-C has a lot of way to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

UITableCell is a V of the MVC pattern. You should think about your cells in the terms of a model objects storing cell's state. That's why Apple separated UITableViewDataSource from the rest of the related API.